# Getting Github Repository Metadata Without Cloning or Pulling

Tags: github, metadata

Without pulling or cloning all the files from a repository on the Github, is there a way to just access branch, tag, and commit SHA ID numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from the github API http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "commit": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
      "author": {
        "name": "Monalisa Octocat",
        "email": "support@github.com",
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "Monalisa Octocat",
        "email": "support@github.com",
        "date": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
      },
      "message": "Fix all the bugs",
      "tree": {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tree/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
        "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"
      }
    },
    "author": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "somehexcode",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat"
    },
    "committer": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "somehexcode",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat"
    },
    "parents": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
        "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```